# How to destructure an object with multiple sub-keys of the same name

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

What's the cleanest way to destructure the following object?

```
const e = {
  target: {
    userid: {
      value: 'abc'
    },
    password: {
      value: 'xyz'
    }
  }
}
```

The object is how an HTML form returns data and I'm trying to retrieve values using ONLY destructuring. My attempt was:

```
const {target: {userid: {value}, password: {value}}} = e;
```

But it chokes on the two `value`s having the same property name. Any ES6 alternative?

Comment: Side note: `e: {...}` should be `e={...}`

Comment: But you must be sure that the keys are going to be available. Otherwise, you have to default the destructured object (parent).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can destructure the value properties into distinctly named variables by placing the names after a `:`, e.g.

```
const {target: {userid: {value: myUserId}, password: {value: myPassword}}} = e;
```

`myUserId` will now have the value 'abc' and `myPassword` 'xyz'